# How do I debug errors like this in Codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I have an app that works well on the simulator. I did an Android build and installed on a device. Now , several functionalities don't work. The debug log I receive contain several errors of this sort

```
    [EDT] 0:23:31,275 - Exception in Ziemozi version 1.0
[EDT] 0:23:31,275 - OS and
[EDT] 0:23:31,275 - Error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.codename1.ab.l.n(int)' on a null object reference
[EDT] 0:23:31,276 - Current Form null
[EDT] 0:23:31,276 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.codename1.ab.l.n(int)' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.codename1.ab.l.n(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.codename1.g.j.a(InfiniteScrollAdapter.java:156)
    at com.codename1.g.j.a(InfiniteScrollAdapter.java:143)
    at com.codename1.ab.aa.t(InfiniteContainer.java:177)
    at com.codename1.ab.aa$5.run(InfiniteContainer.java:193)
    at com.codename1.ab.r.n(Display.java:1298)
    at com.codename1.ab.r.l(Display.java:1242)
    at com.codename1.ab.r.k(Display.java:1130)
    at com.codename1.ab.ao.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
```

How do I debug this or how does it arise so I can fix it?

Comment: `com.codename1.ab.l.n` is obfuscated. Maybe you can get a log with the actual name of that method trying to test on your Android device a "debug" build instead than a "release" build (see "Codename One Settings", "Android settings", "Generate Build").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when one of the components returned from `InfiniteContainer` is null. E.g. you did something like:

```
public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount);
    // ... 
    return cmps;
}
```

cmps is a valid array that's bigger than 0 but one of its elements is null.